# Dropdown works different with .find().first() and .next() methods

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown, which will open when a button (image) is clicked and close when anything is clicked (same button, one of the options or just somewhere on the page). I don't need to hide dropdown when it's not hovered. An important function is that the dropdown must slide down smoothly (I used `slideToggle()`).

I noticed, that if I reference to my dropdown using:

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().slideToggle(150);
```

It closes itself as desired. But there is no smooth drop down at all. On the other hand:

```
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(150);
```

would do smooth opening nicely within given time, but this time it doesn't close, unless the main button is clicked again.

How can I combine these two behaviours? I couldn't find any docs saying, that `slideToggle()` won't work with `.find().first()`.

[JSfiddle with the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/0a5atxaq/2/)

Comment: I guess the immediate downvote came because of old jsfiddle pasted by an accident. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error is that you are triggering the button click, while you should trigger the `<body>` click if you want to do an action when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Please check the below code and I hope that this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click", function(e) {
     var clickedElem = e.toElement ; //Get the clicked element
      
      if (clickedElem.type == "button" && $(clickedElem).hasClass("button-m")) { //If we clicked the button element
        if ($(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status") == "opened") { //If list is opened, change the data-status to closed
          $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "closed") ;
        }
        else {
          $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "opened") ; //If list is not opened, change the data-status to opened
        }

        $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(150); //Toggle Slide
      }
      else { //If we clicked anywhere other than the button
        if ($(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status") == "opened") { //If the list is opened, close the list
          $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "closed") ;
          $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(150);
        }
      }
    }) ;
 })
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
       <button type="button" class="button-m button-c" data-toggle="dropdown">
           <img class="tile-icon" :src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports">
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-maps" data-status="opened">
           <li>
               <a href="#">object 1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#">object 2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#">object 3</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#">object 4</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

I am triggering the `<body>` click, and if the clicked element is the button, then the list will open and close, while if the clicked element is not the button, the list will only close.

To get the status of the list, a `data-status` tag is added, and I am updating it each time the list is opened/closed

> Updated Code:

Below is the updated code,
`e.ToElement` replaced with `e.target`.

Removed `slideToggle` and using `slideUp` and `slideDown`

Tested on the latest versions of:

- Google Chrome
- Mozilla Firefox
- Safari
- Opera
- Internet Explore

```js
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    var clickedElem = e.target ; //Get the clicked element

    if ($(clickedElem).hasClass("maindiv") || $(clickedElem).parents(".maindiv").length > 0) { //If we clicked the button element
     if ($(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status") == "opened") { //If list is opened, change the data-status to closed
      $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "closed") ;
      $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(250) ;
     }
     else {
      $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "opened") ; //If list is not opened, change the data-status to opened
      $('.dropdown-menu').slideDown(250) ;
     }
    }
    else { //If we clicked anywhere other than the button
     if ($(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status") == "opened") { //If the list is opened, close the list
      $(".dropdown-menu").attr("data-status", "closed") ;
      $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(250) ;
     }
    }
   }) ;
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.maindiv {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  display:none;
}
.dropdown-menu li{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="maindiv">
        <button type="button" class="button-m button-c" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <div>
            <img class="tile-icon" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract"><span>List</span>
          </div>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-maps" data-status="closed">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="button-c" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/city"/> <span>Menu 1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="button-c" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports"/> <span>Menu 2</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="button-c" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics"/> <span>Menu 3</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="button-c" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/food"/> <span>Menu 4</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've just noticed I have pasted an old link to the jsfiddle... It's already updated. I'll try to follow your advice with the new one, thank you.

Comment: I read event.toElement should be substituted with event.target in order to work properly on multiple browsers. This one works only i Chrome and the code supports only opening, not closing the list.